# How to install windows 2012 drivers for intel ICH8 raid?

Tags: raid, windows-server-2012, software-raid, intel-rst

I must install windows 2012 on a Dell T5400 precision workstation.

The computer has 2 SSD configured in RAID 1 (mirror).

I cannot find drivers to report their state in windows. There is no point to use raid 1 if I cannot be warned when there's a failure.

Thanks

Comment: I would contact Dell and request the release Windows Server 2012 drivers for their hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Win7 Driver. You'd be surprised how often this works. For a long time Vista drivers would work in 7 before 7 was widely adopted, and even today when installing 8, you can get away with using 7 drivers. For 2012 there's one gotcha, and that's you need to use Win7 x64 drivers, as their is no x86 version of 2012.

Comment: There is no windows 7 version on Dell website

Comment: Have you tried searching by serial? what's the service tag of that model?

Comment: There's no win 7 drivers, but vista x64 is working. thx

Comment: I have noticed that the manager kills the system (blue screen) when clicking on refresh after replacing a drive.

Answer (score 0):

Was not that easy to find a working driver even for windows 7.

I used this one and it worked : http://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER98298M/2/Intel_Rapid-Storage-Technolo_A04_R264763.exe
Note that it require .NET 3.5 feature to be installed.

I did not find a way to send alert by mail yet

Comment: but the windows 7 driver worked? please mark my answer as the solution then.